# How do you execute a script second time around if it fails on the first attempt?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is my first script:

```
var curHp : int = 300.0;
var maxHp : int = 300.0;
var slot2 : int = 1.0;
var money : int = 25.0;
var upgrade : int = 1.0;
var curXp : int = 0.0;
var maxXp : int = 500.0;
var level : int = 1.0;
```

This is my second script `playerAttack.js`:

```
var enemyHealth : int = 100;

function Update() {
    if (this.enemyHealth <= 0) {
        curXp += 10;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

function OnTriggerStay(col : Collider) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "attackArea")
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
            this.enemyHealth -=100;
}
```

I'm encountering a problem with this `curXp += 10`. Unity 3D can't find `curXp`. How may I resolve this problem? The error given is:

```
Unknown identifier "curXp += 10;".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variables aren't global like that.  Either move all the variables from  the first script to `playerAttack.js` or make the variables `public static` in the first script and access them like `FirstScript.curXp`

Answer (score -1):

This error often pops up when you try to mix c# scripts and JavaScript scripts. You wrote all of your code in javascript though, so this isn't the problem. Does one of your scripts have a .cs extension?

Also, how are you including your first script with the second. If that fails, you could possibly get this error as well.

Third but you are trying to set all your int variables as a float.

A Int is a variable that stores a number with no decimal(like 10).
A Float is a variable that stores a number with a decimal(like 10.5f).

Remove the decimal from the variables in the script on top.

Also, I would ask this on [unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/) as well, as it has a larger community of unity3d users after unity shut down their stack overflow site.